# Quill.js strips custom tags such as <ins> and <hr> from content

Tags: tags, ads, quill

I added custom blot to quill editor to allow the content admin to insert google ads ins tag into the content through the CMS, and it works fine when I insert the element to the content, but Quill strips the ins tags when content is loaded back to editor from DB. I checked the DB, the content is properly saved and loaded back through codeigniter. When I echo the content directly to HTML it displays properly, but when it's loaded to the quill editor it's being replaced with `<p><br><p>`.

Can anyone please figure out what I'm missing here?

Thanks a lot!

Here's my JS file

```
var toolbarOptions = [ ['bold', 'underline'], 
  ['link', 'image'],
  [{ 'list': 'ordered'}, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
  [{ 'indent': '-1'}, { 'indent': '+1' }],          
  [{ 'direction': 'rtl' }],                         
  [{ 'header': [ 2, 3, 4, false] }],
  [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],          
  [{ 'align': [] }],
  ['clean'],
  ['adBanner'],
  ['hr']

];
// adBanner icon //
var icons = Quill.import("ui/icons");
    icons["adBanner"] = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="16" width="18" viewBox="0 0 576 512"><path d="M64 32C28.7 32 0 60.7 0 96V416c0 35.3 28.7 64 64 64H512c35.3 0 64-28.7 64-64V96c0-35.3-28.7-64-64-64H64zM229.5 173.3l72 144c5.9 11.9 1.1 26.3-10.7 32.2s-26.3 1.1-32.2-10.7L253.2 328H162.8l-5.4 10.7c-5.9 11.9-20.3 16.7-32.2 10.7s-16.7-20.3-10.7-32.2l72-144c4.1-8.1 12.4-13.3 21.5-13.3s17.4 5.1 21.5 13.3zM208 237.7L186.8 280h42.3L208 237.7zM392 256a24 24 0 1 0 0 48 24 24 0 1 0 0-48zm24-43.9V184c0-13.3 10.7-24 24-24s24 10.7 24 24v96 48c0 13.3-10.7 24-24 24c-6.6 0-12.6-2.7-17-7c-9.4 4.5-19.9 7-31 7c-39.8 0-72-32.2-72-72s32.2-72 72-72c8.4 0 16.5 1.4 24 4.1z"/></svg>';
    icons["hr"] = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="16" width="14" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path d="M32 288c-17.7 0-32 14.3-32 32s14.3 32 32 32l384 0c17.7 0 32-14.3 32-32s-14.3-32-32-32L32 288zm0-128c-17.7 0-32 14.3-32 32s14.3 32 32 32l384 0c17.7 0 32-14.3 32-32s-14.3-32-32-32L32 160z"/></svg>';

// INIT QUILL //

var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  placeholder: 'Enter your post text here',
  theme: 'snow',
  scrollingContainer: 'html',
  clipboard: {
    matchVisual: false,
  },
  modules: {
    toolbar: toolbarOptions
  },
  formats: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'link', 'image', 'ad', 'hr'],
});

//Custom Hr tag
var Delta = Quill.import('delta');
quill.clipboard.addMatcher(Node.ELEMENT_NODE, function(node, delta) {
  return new Delta().insert(node);
});
let BlockEmbed = Quill.import('blots/block/embed');

class Hr extends BlockEmbed {
  static create(value) {
      let node = super.create(value);
      return node;
  }
}

Hr.blotName = 'hr';
Hr.tagName = 'hr';

Quill.register({
  'formats/hr': Hr
});

var customHrHandler = function(){
  // get the position of the cursor
  var range = quill.getSelection();
  if (range) {
      // insert the <hr> where the cursor is
      quill.insertEmbed(range.index,"hr","null")
  }
}


$('.ql-hr').click(function() {
  let range = quill.getSelection(true);
  quill.insertText(range.index, '\n', Quill.sources.USER);
  quill.insertEmbed(range.index + 1, 'hr', Quill.sources.USER);
  quill.setSelection(range.index + 2, Quill.sources.SILENT);
});

// CustomAdBlot
class adBannerBlot extends BlockEmbed {
  static create(value) {
    let node = super.create(value);
    if (value && value.client) {
      node.setAttribute('data-ad-client', value.client);
    }
    if (value && value.slot) {
      node.setAttribute('data-ad-slot', value.slot);
    }
    if (value && value.class) {
      node.setAttribute('class', value.class);
    }
    // Add other attributes as needed
    return node;
  }

  static value(node) {
    return {
      client: node.getAttribute('data-ad-client'),
      slot: node.getAttribute('data-ad-slot'),
      class: node.getAttribute('class'),
      // Add other attributes as needed
    };
  }
}

adBannerBlot.blotName = 'ad';
adBannerBlot.tagName = 'ins';

Quill.register({
  'formats/ad': adBannerBlot,
});

$('.ql-adBanner').click(function () {
  let range = quill.getSelection(true);
  quill.insertText(range.index, '\n', Quill.sources.USER);
  quill.insertEmbed(range.index + 1, 'ad', { client: 'CLIENT-CODE', slot: 'CLIENT-SLOT', class:'adsbygoogle' }, Quill.sources.USER);
  quill.setSelection(range.index + 2, Quill.sources.SILENT);
});
```

Here is the pho code to load the content to Quill element
($post is an object retrieved from db model)

```
<div id="editor"><?php echo $post['content']; ?></div>
```

Here is the CSS to visually display the ins tags on the page

```
ins.adsbygoogle
{
    background-color: $gray;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: $light-gray;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 200px;
    min-width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid $gray;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;

    &::before
    {
        display: block;
        content: "Advertisement";
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left:50%;
        transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
        color: $white;
        z-index: 0;
    }

    &::after
    {
        display: none;
    }

    iframe 
    {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
    }
}
```